# Как создать одностраничный сайт с помощью switch

Tags: php

```
<?php //$_GET[""];
$page=""; ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title><?php $title ?></title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="">
<table width="100%" border="1" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="6%"><!---Меню банка--->
    Меню<br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    </td>
<td width="94%"><div align="center"><img src="file/img/grin.gif" width="200" height="200" align="top"><img src="file/img/logo_water.gif" width="200" height="200" align="top"></div><br>
<?php 
// Выборка файлов
switch($page)
{
    case "vhod_gg.php":
    include "/file/vhod_gg.php"; break; // Вход
    case "index_gg.php":
    include "/file/index_gg.php"; break; // Главная страница

}
?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Файлы, как видите, я подключил. Но как мне перейти на один из них? Опишите пожалуйста

Comment: теперь то я знаю какие "программисты" пишут банк-клиенты...<br />
....Меню банка...<br />
так как моя работа связана с эникеем в том числе... разработчикам сих продуктов так хочется что нибудь оторвать... особенно за совместимость последних только с тупым браузером, которого лиса просила помолчать...

Answer (score 1):

А может вы хотя бы `$page` к чему-нибудь привяжете? У меня не свитч, я пользуюсь правилами `if`:

```
if(!$_GET) {
  echo 'главная';
}elseif($_GET[page] == vhod) {
  include "/file/vhod_gg.php";
}elseif($_GET[page] == anypage) {
  include "еще_какой_нибудь_файл.php";
}
```

Вызывать так `index.php?page=vhod/anypage/etc...`

А, и еще по негласному правилу, имена файлов/адресов пишутся не транслитом а английским названием, не ленитесь переводить имена, к примеру `login` а не `vhod`)))

```
$page=$_GET[page];
switch($page)
{
    case "vhod_gg":
    include "/file/vhod_gg.php"; break; // Вход
    case "index_gg":
    include "/file/index_gg.php"; break; // Главная страница

}

вызов index.php?page=vhod_gg/index_gg/etc...
```

Comment: Про транслит верно подмечено, вы же не 1С-шник :D

Comment: :) короче, если по русски, сделай $page=$_GET['page'] ну как то так) и вызывай в адресной строке аналогично моему примеру)
ЗЫ, 1С язык не знаю, там что транслит??:)

Comment: Ааа, чуть не забыл, сделайте дефаулт, иначе будет выводиться пустая страница если `index.php` просто открывать без `?page=any`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php 
    // Выборка файлов
    switch($page)
    {
        case "vhod_gg.php":
        header("Location: file/vhod_gg.php"); break; // Вход
        case "index_gg.php":
        header("Location: file/index_gg.php"); break; // Главная страница

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Какой тайный смысл от вашего коммента?
Вопрос был как вызвать, а не копипастнуть то, что написал автор)

Comment: В смысле?